# Clicking a textview in a Webview causes screen to jump and Webview scroll to become infinite

Tags: android, webview, salesforce

I am writing an app with the Salesforce Android SDK.

We have a custom website that is used for the login landing page that has a username and password field.

Clicking on the first field brings focus and keyboard as expected. Clicking on the second field (regardless of which is clicked first) causes the screen to jump up and down for half a second and then leaves the screen so that you can scroll infinitely, even beyond the background image. No matter how far you scroll the scrollbar is stuck at the top. However to scroll back up you have to scroll the same distance you scrolled down.

While this is from the LoginActivity from the Salesforce SDK, I have modified the file to show the action bar at the top.

What is causing this behavior and how can I make it stop, changing zoom controls in the webviews settings does not seem to help.

The same screen in iOS does not seem to have this same behavior.

Worth noting, the defect does not appear in the devices chrome browser.

[The Class in Salesforce SDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/blob/master/libs/SalesforceSDK/src/com/salesforce/androidsdk/ui/LoginActivity.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Salesforce SDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/blob/master/libs/SalesforceSDK/res/layout/sf__login.xml)

There is a ScrollView  in a WebView. This shouldn't be necessary and may cause a problem such as the one you described. Changing the ScrollView to LinearLayout should fix the issue.